# Using a variable from one class in another

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I am trying to make an iOS app using Objective-C. However, I have been running into a problem. Basically, I am setting the value of myVariable in one class, and then trying to use it in another class. Here is my code.

```
//This is in Class2
#import Class1
Class1 *class = [[Class1 alloc] init];

//Then I try to log my variable
NSLog(@"%@", Class1.myVariable);
```

I don't want to set myVariable to anything in class2, because I want it to stay the same value as it was in class1. However, with my code, myVariable returns to (null) in class2. In class1 myVariable is 6. Does anyone think they could help me? Thanks!

Here is an example of my code in Class1.

```
- (IBAction)six:(id)sender {
_numberOfDice = 6;
 [self saveNumber];
self.checkmark.hidden = YES;
self.checkmark2.hidden = YES;
self.checkmark3.hidden = YES;
self.checkmark4.hidden = YES;
self.checkmark5.hidden = YES;
self.checkmark6.hidden = NO;
}
-(void) saveNumber {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [paths lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"number"];
_amountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _numberOfDice];
BOOL isSuccessful = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:_amountString toFile:filePath];
if(isSuccessful) {
    NSLog(@"It has saved.");
    NSLog(@"the string is %@", _amountString);
    NSLog(@"The integer is %d", _numberOfDice);

}
}

-(void) loadNumber {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [paths lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"number"];
_amountString = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
if(!_amountString) {
    _amountString = [[NSString alloc] init];
}
}
```

As you can see in the code above, someone can click the button 6, and _numberOfDice is set to 6. Then I convert it to a string and save that string. When I run viewDidLoad, I load the number. The string(_amountString) is the variable I want to pass on to Class2. I set it in Class1, then I want to pass it on to Class2.

Comment: Post your code for `Class1`. More than likely what is happening is you have code in `Class1` that sets myVariable = 6 after some time. However, when you do `Class1 *class = [[Class1 alloc] init];`, you create a brand new copy of `Class1`. This means if you don't set `myVariable` in either the `init` or `viewDidLoad`, it won't be set just yet.

Comment: Yes I do set myVariable = 6 in Class1. Basically it is a settings view controller. You can click how much you want myVariable to equal. If you clicked 6, it would equal 6. Then I save the amount, and now I am trying to pass on six(or whatever number the person clicked on) to Class2.

Comment: You are creating a new object of Class1 in Class2. This is very low quality question.

Comment: @user3754646 See my answer to why it's not working. Please look up about what an instance of a class means to understand why your code doesn't work as intended. If this is your first time programming in any language then I suggest you pick up an intro to programming book.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is your problem.

When you edit `myVariable in Class1`, you are doing it for that specific instance. An instance is a specific copy of an object. You can have one instance of `Class1`, or you can have 100 instances of `Class1`. Each will be uniquely different. In your case, you now have 2 `Class1`s. The first one you edit and it knows about `myVariable`. The second one doesn't, because you never hit loadNumber/saveNumber.

So you have your original `Class1` that you were on that you set `myVariable = 6`. However, when you do `Class1 *class = [[Class1 alloc] init];` you create a brand new copy. This is like going to the store and buying a new soda. Even though you have purchased this type of soda before, it's still different because this one is brand new.

Another issue I see is that this is a lot of overkill for saving a number - you're creating a new file for saving the number, then reading from it each time. This is incredibly inefficient and complicated. `NSUserDefaults` is a much better option and makes more sense here.

There are a lot of ways to solve your issue. Honestly I would go with saving `myVariable` in `NSUserDefaults`. Then in `Class2`, you simply read from `NSUserDefaults`. Another solution is to make `myVariable` a static variable on `Class1`, or to save a reference to the `Class1` you edited. But the simplest solution is to save into `NSUserDefaults` and read from it in `Class2`

Comment: The use of NSUserDefaults to pass data from one controller to another is not a good practice either. It is supposed to be used for data that need to be persistent between launches of an app, not within one running of an app. The OP should just pass the data from one controller to the next, in a manner that's been answered thousands of times here on SO.

Comment: @rdelmar I agree with you in most cases, but OP said this was a settings screen + his code is around saving/loading this value. It looks like he's using it to persist between launches of the app. I'll update my answer to specify the suggestion is due to his use case.